# Do babies want to be carried in order to develop their eyes?

Tags: newborn, development, research

There have been a lot of questions on this site regarding the phenomenon of a baby needing to be not only held, but carried.

In my specific situation (7 weeks old baby), my baby wants to be held, in a stomach down position and carried around (simply holding is not enough, neither is carrying in another position).

I have read some research on the topic and have concluded the following:

1. When trouble is afoot and you need to get away quick a crying baby can be a liability. Hence evolution selected for babies, which keep cool, when the mother moves it from A to B.
2. The baby is programmed in a way, that it is not enough to just hold it, you need to be moving while holding, for the instinct to kick in. This is a distinct feature. For example in cats, you only need to hold them by the scruff for the same feature to kick in.

However I think there might be another factor: Boredom. Since my baby wants to be 1) held 2) on its stomach (which gives it a good view) and 3) moving (changing scenery) boredom must be playing a factor here as well? Maybe babies, who are just developing their eyes, need to be carried in order to train their eyes?

Is there any research backing or disproving this?

Comment: Age really matters for behavior of children. And yes, most babies calm down when they are moved around, for some forms of movement. Before they are a couple months old, this is 99% unrelated to the scenery they can see while you're holding them. Quite the opposite - babies usually react stronger to seeing faces than any other visual input.

Comment: How old is your baby? No one can answer from any significant studies without basic information given. Please edit your post. Thanks.

Comment: 7 weeks old today

Comment: Yes i have noticed by 2.5 month old daughter, if she is crying and want us to carry her, as soon as she is taken care of, she is good. **babies want to be carried in order to develop their eyes does not make any sense** But yes babies do need stroking, In Book "I am Okay, You are Okay" author said in infant may even die if stroking is not done for few days.

Comment: @Rishi could you please link to that information about infant death due to lack of stroking? There are literally thousands of infants in orphanages who had emotional problems because of a lack of touch. I have never heard of a child dying of a lack of stroking -- neglect, certainly.

Comment: @Willow - Institutionalized children - overcrowded orphanages - occassionally do develop such significant failure to thrive that it ends in death. But it happens over many months/a few years, not days.

Comment: @anongoodnurse  you are right, however Rishi said a matter of a few days and that was why I asked for stats or a link.

Comment: @Willow Kindly check [this](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2010/apr/21/leaving-baby-to-cry-brain-development-damage), which says **Leaving a distressed baby to cry on a regular basis could be damage the developing brain, according to parenting guru Penelope Leach**, also I apologies as on weekends I don't use this site, I will update the information from the book **"I am Okay, You are Okay"** tonight.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yes are right, Brain Damage could only happens if infant it not taken care for few days or on regular basis. I also apologize for using a very harsh language in my comment 2 days back. But it never happens generally.

Comment: @Rishi Here's the [link to that article you quoted](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2010/apr/21/leaving-baby-to-cry-brain-development-damage)  But while she does say allowing a baby to cry may harm development, it doesn't address the " infant may even die if stroking is not done for few days." That is what concerned me. Thanks.

Comment: @Willow Book ["I'M Okay, you're okay"](http://mindguruindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/MP062_Parenting-Im-OK-Youre-OK.pdf) Chapter 3 The Four Life Position Page Number 36 states **"Stroking, or repetitious bodily contact, is essential to his survival. Without it he will die, if not physically, then psychologically"** Okay i read this book many months back So the author is talking about psychological death but what he is saying is indeed very important and tells the important of physical touch and stroking

Comment: @Rishi  thank you. I did think there was some misunderstanding. I should mention that this book is 'dated', for example Dr Penfield (who happened to be my godfather)  inferred a direct association with neuroscience,  which has not proved  reproducible.  (Much to his disappointment.)

Comment: @Willow thank you, I had to find it in the book, so i started reading it again and thank god i find it soon..;D, the way we remember incidents are actually very different than the reality, so i did not remember it exactly, i am sorry if i misdirected. Indeed this is a serious website for users and i will try to give references with what ever i have to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You baby is just 7 weeks old. Did you walk around when you were pregnant?

Does the baby just want world to continue as it was?

Of course there is a chance that you have one of those wonderful babies who will change the world. Constantly looking around, trying to understand things, feeling new items, seeing the world, smelling and learning.

My first child was an explorer. I took all juice out of both of us before we realized how to fullfill his needs.

We took him to the baby swimming classes until he was 2 years old and visited all child friendly spas nearby. We visited farms to show him new experiences but water was the thing to drain all his energy when he was a baby or toddler. Later when he learned how to climb and play outside games, those did the trick.

As a first aid, try things. Is the baby happy sucking wooden spoon? Can you find music which makes your baby slow down? It could be anything you listened before the birth.

What ever you do, do not teach the baby bad habits. Few examples which I've heard or made myself. Do not teach child to fall asleep **only** in the car. My cousin did fall asleep only when she had a pacifier in her mouth and one loop of a pacifier in each of her fingers. I did teach my son to fall to sleep when I were walking or moving him around (rocking etc.)

And finally the eyes. No, you don't need to do anything. It is actually the brain which is developing. When a baby gets older (s)he learns more complex patterns. At the moment (s)he recognizes just eyes and mouth (smiling or not). Babies can be tricked with big emoticons / smilies to smile. :-)

Usually babies need just food, dry diapers, sleep, enough clothes when cold, and someone to show them the world. I mean, to tell them about the world. Before age of one they just want to see you and your reactions, your happiness.